# Array length undefined in nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to understand whats wrong in my code. Please have a look, may be I am missing something.

```
    const images = await Image.query().where('product_id', product.id).fetch()
    for(let i=0; i< images.length; i++){
        console.log(images[i]) // never comes in.... 
        console.log('Inside in')
    }
    console.log(images.length) // it shows undefined...
    console.log(images)
    return images
```

But I can see my data in browser like this

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

If I console.log(images) I see in my terminal something like this

```
   VanillaSerializer {
   rows: 
   [ Image {
   __setters__: [Array],
   '$attributes': [Object],
   '$persisted': true,
   '$originalAttributes': [Object],
   '$relations': {},
   '$sideLoaded': {},
   '$parent': null,
   '$frozen': false,
   '$visible': undefined,
   '$hidden': undefined },
 Image {
   __setters__: [Array],
   '$attributes': [Object],
   '$persisted': true,
   '$originalAttributes': [Object],
   '$relations': {},
   '$sideLoaded': {},
   '$parent': null,
   '$frozen': false,
   '$visible': undefined,
   '$hidden': undefined } ],
  pages: null,
  isOne: false }
```

I am running nodejs with adonis js framework.

Thank you

Comment: call `images.toJSON()` to make it return json and then you can use it as array.

Comment: Great it works. I messed front end as we are used to getting serilized data in the front end so expected same in nodejs. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `toJSON()` function of `VanillaSerializer` to return the data as json, like the following.

```
 const imageData = await Image.query().where('product_id', product.id).fetch();
 const images = imageData.toJSON();
```

then you can loop through the images like you did.